# Binding text of a label in a template does not work

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, binding, label

I have created a template and I have to assign the value of a variable to a label, I use the binding, but it doesn't work.
This is the code in the cs:

```
AppViewModel vm = new AppViewModel();
        BindingContext = vm;
        InitializeComponent();
```

This is the code in the viewmodel:

```
public class AppViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _utente;

    public AppViewModel()
    {
        Utente = App.UTENTE;
    }

    public string Utente
    {
        get
        {
            return _utente;
        }
        set
        {
            _utente = value;
            //OnPropertyChanged("Utente");
            //PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Utente));
            OnPropertyChanged("utente");
            //PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("utente"));
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

This is the code xaml:

```
                    <Label x:Name="utente" Padding="10, 0, 0, 0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Utente}" FontSize="Large" TextColor="White" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

Comment: where are you binding the label?  Where is the relevant XAML?

Comment: I changed the question

Comment: Also inserting the code of the label

Comment: If you are using Binding, the x:Name of Label can be ignored.You can check my answer,it works well on my side.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using **MVVM** properly, please see my code snippets for your reference.

1.in xaml and code behind:

```
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Utente}"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
```

Behind the xaml:

```
public partial class AppViewPage : ContentPage
{

    AppViewModel vm = new AppViewModel();
    public AppViewPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
        vm.Utente = "utente";
    }
}
```

2.AppViewModel:

```
    public class AppViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 
        private string _utente;
        public string Utente
        {
            get { return _utente; }
            set {
                  _utente = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                   new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Utente)));
            }
        }
        public AppViewModel()
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried to do as you suggested, but it doesn't work for me anyway, maybe it's because I'm doing it in the App.xaml, but I can't give myself explanations, everything goes well but skip the get

Comment: That's weird!Could you please help provide entire sample through Github link so I can help you test and find the root cause?

Comment: I would like to do it, but I have no idea how to do it